# django bootstrap select element one column

Tags: python, django, jinja2

i use djando and bootstrap. I use a form with a method POST and "select" option. I try to select elements belong to a table. I can see the database elements, but elements it's not showing in a column, they showing in a row  (one consecutive to another).

I try to figure what is the error, but i not fix it. It's my firts time with django and python;-)!

Thanks in advance!

[Elements in a row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBrnh.png)

The code:

```
`
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'consorcio' %}">{% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name_consorcio" required name="name_consorcio" placeholder="Nombre Consorcio:"><br/>
                            </div>   
                            <div class="col">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="direccion_consorcio" required name="direccion_consorcio" placeholder="Direccion Consorcio:"><br/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cuit" required name="cuit" placeholder="CUIT:"><br/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                <select class="form-select">
                                    <option selected>Seleccionar Administracion:
                                        <option value="1">
                                                <ul>
                                                {% for a in all_consorcio %} 
                                                    <li>{{ a.administracion.name_administracion }}</li>
                                                {% endfor %}
                                                </ul>
                                        </option>
                                    </option>
                                </select>
                            </div>   
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Guardar">`
```

```
                </form><br>
```

I tried to modificate the blucle for and add other stuff, like 
 and , etc...

Comment: Take the effort to properly format your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the format you want:

Each *all_consorcio* item will be it's own an option in the Dropdown

- 5 items in the list => 5 (+1 default) options in the dropdown.

```html
<div class="col">
  <select class="form-select" name="SOMEFIELD_consorcio">
    <option selected>Seleccionar Administracion:</option>

    {% for a in all_consorcio %} 
      <option value="{{ a.pk }}">
        {{ a.administracion.name_administracion }}
      </option>
    {% endfor %}

  </select>
</div>
```

**Note:** change `SOMEFIELD_consorcio` to the actual field name

##### Per `value`

the `value` attribute is what will be posted when the form submits.
I've set it as `{{ a.pk }}` as I'm assuming the form field is a ForignKey;
if it's not try changing it to `{{ a.administracion.name_administracion }}` or some other value.